# IE 11 Developer Tools Issue - Exception in window.onload

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-11, developer-tools

I installed Internet Explorer 11 on my Windows 7 machine and it's not building the DOM in DOM Explorer. Does any one know about this issue? I tried to uninstall and re-install IE many times, but the problem still persists. The DOM Explorer tabs shows error shown in image -
[image]

Comment: You aren't the only one. [Imposible use F12 Developer Tools (Exception in window.onload: Error: An error has ocurredJSPlugin.3005](http://nerdanswer.com/answer.php?q=794944) and [Imposible use F12 Developer Tools (Exception in window.onload: Error: An error has ocurredJSPlugin.3005](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-windows_7/imposible-use-f12-developer-tools-exception-in/09b4f305-e436-4615-a8a5-705b0bc85bbd) also report this issue, but no one has come up with an answer yet. They are both the same person.

Comment: Does this occur on every website? If not which website?
or are you trying to debug a local file that uses the file protocol

Comment: Yes, it happens for every webpage. I have tried restarting machine many times, but no result. And i am not trying to debug local file.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This security update fixed it for me and [others involved](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-windows_7/imposible-use-f12-developer-tools-exception-in/09b4f305-e436-4615-a8a5-705b0bc85bbd):

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44431

Make sure you install the correct version of the security update. There is a different version for x86 installs of Windows 7, too.

Comment: It takes forever to load.

Comment: Installing the update fixed the issue for me but a new (different, related to Emulation) issue arrived.

Comment: Did not fix it for me - I'm still getting the stream of "DOM7005: Indexed DB is only availalbe..." when using local file system loaded HTML and Javascript.

Answer (score 5):

I have Windows 7 (x86: 32 bit) and the top answer here said it wasn't applicable to my system. I had to use this one: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=45134

Comment: I use virtual machine from IE testdrive to test IE versions, so also my virtual machine was 32 bit (x86). I used: KB3087038 instead. I guess you can always just search for any 'Cumulative Security Update Internet Explorer 11 WIndows (your version here)'.

Answer (score 3):

I'm on Windows Server 2003 R2 x64 running IE 11. This update fixed it for me:

https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms14-080

(Martijn, I'm reposting this after having deleted my answer on [An error has ocurredJSPlugin.3005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301393/an-error-has-ocurredjsplugin-3005/36575621#36575621).  This question is older, so I flagged the other one as a duplicate question and left the answer here)