# An error has ocurredJSPlugin.3005

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer, browser, ie11-developer-tools

I installed IE11 on server 2008r2.
I was trying to debug using IE11 and I am having the following error. The error I am having in the Dom Explorer tab is:

**Diagnostic:**

`Exception in window.onload: Error: An error has ocurredJSPlugin.3005`

**Stack Trace:**

```
Error: An error has ocurredJSPlugin.3005 at getString (res://C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\F12Resources.dll/23/pluginhost/plugin.f12.js:5021:27) at ToolWindowHelpers.loadString (res://C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\F12Resources.dll/23/Common/CommonMerged.js:5803:13) at TabPanes..
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE 11 Developer Tools Issue - Exception in window.onload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435753/ie-11-developer-tools-issue-exception-in-window-onload)

Comment: This is still an issue in Jan 2017, on a fresh Windows 7 install having downloaded IE11 from the Microsoft website. Crazy they don't bundle the fix with IE11 in the first place.

Comment: Still an issue in April 2017

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Install the latest cumulative IE update :

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45134 （32 bit）
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45154 （64 bit）

Comment: Did not work. Windows says this update is not applicable

Comment: @MargusPala you probably picked the 32 bit version and have a 64 bit OS or vice versa.

Answer (score 14):

> I found the cause for this problem. I upgraded Internet explorer directly from IE8 to IE11. So I got the above said error during debugging.
>
> Then I downgraded Internet explorer from IE11 to previous one(IE8). Then upgraded IE8 to IE10. Again upgraded IE10 to IE11. Now the debugger for IE11 is working fine.

Comment: Good explanation ! (implicit)

Comment: Oh Microsoft... could you be any worse

Comment: I got that error after an upgrade from IE10 to IE11

Comment: I also got same error after upgrading IE 9 to 10 and then from IE10 to IE 11

Answer (score 11):

Just a small update for Season714's answer if you're using Windows 7:

M$ did some magic things cause `Windows 7 Updates take forever`, so before you install those IE updates, you have to **disable your network adapter** first.

By doing that, that update installation will start in few seconds and the error will be fixed. But if you don't, Windows Update will run first and it would take forever to complete.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in my Windows 7 freshly installed virtual machine.

Apparently all of the updates were not installed immediately. I had to install Windows updates several times and restart also serveral times until all of the updates were installed and the issue went away.

First update upgraded from IE8 to IE11. And after that I think it was 2 more updates to have it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

write this in your code into  tag like this:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
</head>
```

if someone have the same problem