# fullcalendar4.2.0 datesRender error (only ie)

Tags: javascript, calendar, internet-explorer-11

I am customizing fullcalendar4.2.0. I get a "datesRender error" only in IE (v.11), but Firefox and Chrome operated well.

Help me!

```js
    datesRender: function(info) {//일 삭제   viewSkeletonRender
        if(info.view.type == 'dayGridMonth') {
            info.el.querySelectorAll('.fc-day-number').forEach(function(v,i,a) {
                a[i].innerText = v.innerText.replace(/일/, '');
            });
        } else if(info.view.type == 'timeGridWeek') {
            info.el.querySelectorAll('th.fc-day-header a').forEach(function(v,i,a) {
                var s = v.innerText.trim().split('.');
                a[i].innerHTML = '<small>'+s[2]+'<\/small>'+s[1];
            });
        }
    }
```

Error message in IE:

> exception in window.onload:Error:An error has accourredJSPlugin,3005

Answer (score 0):

Try to download and install the IE update:

This is 32 bit: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=45134

This is 64 bit: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=45154

More details, please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301393/an-error-has-ocurredjsplugin-3005) and [this link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/imposible-use-f12-developer-tools-exception-in/09b4f305-e436-4615-a8a5-705b0bc85bbd).